# HostListener not listen output emitter

Tags: angular

I have a child component that emits an `@Output` emitter. I am trying to capture the event from parent component using `HostListener`.

Is that possible? I have the link to show the issue.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <button (click)="emitAction()">Emit action</button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Output() myCustomEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  emitAction() {
    this.myCustomEvent.emit("any new object");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  @HostListener('document:myCustomEvent', ['$event'])
  log(event) {
    alert(event);
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Ng on init');
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', (e) => {
      alert('ADD EVENT LISTENER');
    });
  }
  
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customevent-hostlist-addeventlist-edrrby?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: `@Output` event is not a browser custom event. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customevent-hostlist-addeventlist-qawve1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I am just trying. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customevent-hostlist-addeventlist-edrrby?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question, but if you ask why the @Hostlistener does not get 'myCustomEvent', that's not how inter-component communication works (or maybe I've just never seen it like that).
Try writing the event emitter in your father component (in this case, the AppComponent) html where you bind the child component using the custom tag.

Example:

```
// fatherComponent.html
<app-child-component [myInput]="fromFatherToChild" (myOutput)="fromChildToFather($event)"></app-child-component>
```

Brackets are 'downwards' or Inputs, parantheses are 'upwards' or outputs (hence, the 'banana box' seen in [(ngModel)] is both)

```
// childComponent.ts
@Input() public myInput: any;
@Output() public myOutput: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

//further down you can emit this via
this.myOuptut.emit("this is my output")
```

the onMyCustomEvent function references to a function in your father component typescript:

```
// AppComponent.ts
public fromChildToFather(message: any): void {
  console.log(message);
```

}

in this case, you get: 'this is my output' inside the Father Components onMyCustomEvent function.

Comment: Thanks. I know this, but I saw it somewhere it is possible to listen to the output emitter event.